# Getting formatted_address components from GeocoderResult

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

GeocoderResult returns an array of objects (I have seen the number of array elements range from 1 in Antarctica to 16 in Tokyo).  Each of the objects in the array include the following properties:

- address_components:  An array including multiple objects describing the address.  Each of these objects includes a long_name property (string), short_name property (string), and type property (array, and also described below)
- formatted_address: an intuitive single string describing the address
- geometry: deals with longitude/latitude/viewpoint
- type: described by https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes.

The first object in the returned array appears to be the most descriptive physical address (is this always the case?), and its included "formatted_address" seems to always meet my needs.  Problem is I don't want one string but each of the parts.

For instance, a typical USA formatted_address might be the following:

- Van Buren, MI, USA
- State Highway 244, Roundup, MT 59072, USA
- 24 West 18th Avenue, Spokane, WA 99203, USA

For these three formatted_addresses, I would like to get the following:

```
{address:null, street: null, city:"Van Buren", state:"MI", zipcode: null, country:"USA"}
{address:null, street: "State Highway 244", city:"Roundup", state:"MT", zipcode: 59072, country:"USA"}
{address:24, street: "West 18th Avenue", city:"Spokane", state:"WA ", zipcode: 99203, country:"USA"}
```

Should I just try to parse the formatted_address?  Or should do I use address_components, and somehow try to extract the parts I need?  The second solution seems best and might look like the following, but dealing with the type array and short/long names makes it difficult.

The following works okay if I call getAddressParts(GeocoderResult[0].address_components).

```
function getProp(a,type,lng) {
    var j,rs;
    loop:
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < a[i].types.length; j++) {
            if(a[i].types[j]==type) {
                rs=a[i][lng]
                break loop;
            }
        }
    }
    return rs;
}

function getAddressParts(a) {
    var o={};
    o.street_number=getProp(a,'street_number','long_name');
    o.route=getProp(a,'route','long_name'); //Street
    o.establishment=getProp(a,'establishment','long_name'); //Used for parks and the like
    o.locality=getProp(a,'locality','long_name');   //City
    if(!o.locality){o.locality=getProp(a,'sublocality','long_name');}   //Some city not available, use this one (needed for in lake michigan)?
    if(!o.locality){o.locality=getProp(a,'administrative_area_level_2','long_name');}   //Some city not available, use this one (needed for in lake michigan)?
    o.administrative_area_level_1=getProp(a,'administrative_area_level_1','short_name');    //State
    o.country=getProp(a,'country','short_name')+'A';    //A is for usA, and is just being used for testing
    o.postal_code=getProp(a,'postal_code','long_name');
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `address_components`. In a `formatted_address` you won't know which path denotes which administrative level.

Comment: Thanks Salman,  I revised my sample code to something that actually kind of works.  There are still a few cases where it doesn't completely match Google's formatted_address I am tried to work around it using establishment, sublocality, and administrative_area_level_2, but maybe shouldn't worry about it.  Any suggestions?  Thanks